# Public IP address used by a kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I wanted to check the address that a pod uses to connect to a FTP server.
I wanted to test it by running `kubectl   -n cdol exec -it pod-namer  -- curl ipinfo.io/ip` but the connection is blocked by  an engress policy.

I know the CLUSTER-IP of the pod. It has no EXTERNAL-IP.
I know the CLUSTER-IP of the service that pod uses.
I know the node the pod is running so I am able to check the network interfaces in Instana monitoring tool. But all the IPs are private IPs, how can I know what IP other services sees when a pod is connecting to them?

Comment: If other pods connect via the service, they use the cluster-ip of the service. If other pods directly connect the pod, then that's the cluster-ip of the pod.

Comment: Thanks. The question was about connecting to external services and public IP.

Comment: If the pod is directly connecting to an external service, that service will see the connection from the host of that pod.

Comment: @BurakSerdar or the IP of any NAT or Internet Gateway which sits "in front" of the cluster, not necessarily the IP of the Node upon which the Pod is scheduled

Comment: @mdaniel, yes, thx for the correction.

Comment: Are you using cloud env (gke) or bare metal env?